# Google search does not display my favicons

Tags: seo, google-search, favicon

I have some favicon problems with Google search. I noticed that two of my webpages are displayed in Google search, but there are no favicons next to the link in the Google search listing, like this:

[image]

I have checked that when I view a webpage's favicon with this URL, it shows the right favicon but not in Google search: `https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com`

I have used same favicon tags than other webpages, and next to the other webpages Google search shows their favicons.

These are the favicon tags I'm using:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2d89ef">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile-150x150.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#382d57">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="browserconfig.xml" />
```

I used an online site to generate the above.

Answer (score 7):

The icons sizes you specified contradict **[Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/favicon-in-search#guidelines)**:

> Your favicon must be a multiple of 48px square, for example: 48x48px,
> 96x96px, 144x144px and so on. SVG files don't have a specific size.
> Any valid favicon format is supported. Google will rescale your image
> to 16x16px for use in search results, so make sure that it looks good
> at that resolution. Caution: Don't provide a 16x16px favicon.

Use dimensions in multiples of 48x48.

Comment: +1 bc don't 16x16

Comment: I don't understand this advice from Google.   Scaling down an image to 16x16 is never going to look as good as an image designed for 16x16.  Favicons are displayed 16x16 everywhere.  Not sure why Google wouldn't just use that standard size.

Comment: Thanks for answers ! I have following favicons in all my sites, also in sites whose favicons shows in Google search, so all of my sites have same favicon formats and sizes, no differents. Png format favicon sizes: 16x16, 32x32, apple-touch-icon 180x180, manifest file 192x192, 512x512. Ico format favicon 32x32 and mstile 150x150. It is strange that when I test what favicon Google have from site whose favicon does not show on Google search with https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com, it shows right favicon there but no in Google search.

Comment: And it is also strange that Google shows some of my sites favicons in Google search although those sites have exactly same favicons than sites whose favicons do not show in Google search. So, can I try something yet or do I just hope that Google accepts some of my sites favicons ?